# This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I get this error when I use a Bottom NavBar using GetX, main screen have a Controller and I add a observable for management the Bottom NavBar state. Each item have a Controller and I add a observable too.

> This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
> framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can
> be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of
> its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because
> the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
> dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might
> not visit this widget during this build phase.

Comment: That error means you're calling for a build while you're already in a build method. You should share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

i ran into same error. the answer that solved if for me at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485997/3120387

wrap the code that listens for updates according to format below:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {   
  // your obx var, eg. global_variables.appBarTitle.value = "Messages";   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

onReady()  can build    widget.
yes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).